# python- pandas read_excel getting wrong numbers for index_col

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm trying to read a .xlsx file that has 4 sheets each with a Time and Absorbance column like below:

```
Time    Absorbance
0   0.1254
5   0.1278
10  0.128
15  0.1286
20  0.1303
25  0.1295
30  0.1296
35  0.1308
40  0.1301
45  0.1301
50  0.1309
...
```

I want to make a DataFrame with each sheet as a different column and the time as the row index currently my code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd, datetime as dt
import glob, os

runDir = "/Users/AaronT/Documents/Lab/Cascade/DTRA"

if os.getcwd() != runDir:
os.chdir(runDir)

files = glob.glob("PTE_Kinetics*.xlsx")

df = pd.DataFrame()

for each in files:
    sheets = pd.ExcelFile(each).sheet_names

    for sheet in sheets:
        df[sheet] = pd.read_excel(each, sheet, index_col='Time')
        print df
```

However, my output does not have the proper values for the row index:

```
     Forced Wash  Elution    Wash  Flow Through
0         0.1254  -0.0062  0.0544        0.0443
1            NaN      NaN     NaN           NaN
2            NaN      NaN     NaN           NaN
3            NaN      NaN     NaN           NaN
4            NaN      NaN     NaN           NaN
5         0.1278  -0.0027  0.0560        0.0459
6            NaN      NaN     NaN           NaN
7            NaN      NaN     NaN           NaN
8            NaN      NaN     NaN           NaN
9            NaN      NaN     NaN           NaN
10        0.1280  -0.0004  0.0564        0.0467
11           NaN      NaN     NaN           NaN
12           NaN      NaN     NaN           NaN
13           NaN      NaN     NaN           NaN
14           NaN      NaN     NaN           NaN
...
```

Maybe I'm not understanding how the index_col works, I was able to make a separate DataFrame for each sheet with the proper times, but I would prefer they all be on the same one.  Any suggestions?

Edit: Here is a link to the [excel file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5bzqfy3s0aemmmf/PTE_Kinetics_04-30-2015.xlsx?dl=0).

Comment: Care to make available your excel spreadsheets?

Comment: index_col should be an int according to the docs. Does that fix it?

Comment: @AndyHayden I tried making it 0 and 1 and neither worked.

Comment: I added a link to the file @MarkGraph

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, there was a bug in the read_excel docs (which is fixed in master), [index_col can be a sheet name](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.io.excel.read_excel.html) like you've used it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: that each sheet is read correctly, you're just not glueing them up right:

```
In [11]: for sheet in e.sheet_names:
             print(pd.read_excel("PTE_Kinetics_04-30-2015.xlsx", sheet, index_col='Time').head(3))
      Absorbance
Time
0         0.1254
5         0.1278
10        0.1280
      Absorbance
Time
0        -0.0062
5        -0.0027
10       -0.0004
      Absorbance
Time
0         0.0544
5         0.0560
10        0.0564
      Absorbance
Time
0         0.0443
5         0.0459
10        0.0467
```

Rather than as a DataFrame I would prefer to extract them into a dict:

```
d = {}
for sheet in e.sheet_names:
    d[sheet] = pd.read_excel("PTE_Kinetics_04-30-2015.xlsx", sheet, index_col='Time').head(3)
```

Now you can glue them up (without worrying about excel):

```
In [21]: pd.concat(d).unstack(0)
Out[21]:
     Absorbance
        Elution Flow Through Forced Wash    Wash
Time
0       -0.0062       0.0443      0.1254  0.0544
5       -0.0027       0.0459      0.1278  0.0560
10      -0.0004       0.0467      0.1280  0.0564
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to set it the 'time' column as index:

```
In [5]: df= pd.ExcelFile('PTE_Kinetics_04-30-2015.xlsx')

In [7]: sh = df.parse('Forced Wash')

In [8]: sh.head()
Out[8]: 
   Time  Absorbance
0     0      0.1254
1     5      0.1278
2    10      0.1280
3    15      0.1286
4    20      0.1303

In [9]: sh.set_index('Time').head()
Out[9]: 
      Absorbance
Time            
0         0.1254
5         0.1278
10        0.1280
15        0.1286
20        0.1303
```

OR, pass index_col with the column name.

```
In [12]: df.parse(i, index_col='Time').head()
Out[12]: 
      Absorbance
Time            
0         0.0443
5         0.0459
10        0.0467
15        0.0474
20        0.0480
```

It seems you are well on-track with the rest of the process.

Comment: I think it's the glueing up stage which is causing the major issue here, the read excel part was already correct?

Comment: Really ? I got thrown off by this then "@AndyHayden I tried making it 0 and 1 and neither worked."

Comment: The docs seem to not be up to date :(, they say it should be an int - the OP originally used index_col="Time".

Comment: Maybe a thing with the Pandas version then ?

Comment: Ah ha, the docs have been updated in dev http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.io.excel.read_excel.html. I did think that in may be a version issue, but I can reproduce the OP's result. It's due to using an empty DataFrame and then updating it.... pandas seems to get confused!

Comment: I think it's just the docs were out of sync, IIRC you've been able to use a sheet name since 0.13 or even prior. As I say, I can reproduce the OP's weird result with lots of NaNs in 0.16.0. Would be interesting to know what's going on there... that may be a bug.

Comment: I think it's because you are setting a column to a DataFrame. It feels like undefined/edge-case behaviour...